# Calling python file inside PHP file

Tags: php, python, pecl

I have a PHP file which calls Python file. Below is my PHP file contents -

```
<?php
exec('python print_file.py');
?>
```

It calls print_file.py which is my python file. Below is my python file contents -

```
file = open(r'C:\Users\Pavan R\Desktop\expenditures.txt', 'r')
print(file.read())
```

I want the file contents read in my python code to be displayed on my web browser. Problem is that the webpage doesn't display anything. I've googled a lot but failed to solved this. Is there any extension which I should download? Something like PECL Python?

Comment: ...why don't you just call the PHP function `file_get_contents()`? Is this just a simplified example?

Comment: You know that php has a [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) that does exacly what the python script does? Or `cat`, even.

Comment: I don't want to use file_get_contents() as this is just a beginning process to check whether I'm able to print file contents using Python by calling this through PHP. Python file will include more complex computations later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) return the output. Try this if your file has no line breaks:

```
echo exec('python print_file.py');
```

Comment: That won't work; as the link you shared explains, it only returns the last line from the command's output.